# When given a cartesian function, told to plot in parametric, what is the best way to convert them? And why does it make sense to sum and square them?

Tags: calculus, parametric

What is the relationship such that we are able to get trig functions out of equating them, importantly, how can I build that intuition?

I got $x= \sqrt{(5)^2-y^2}$ then subbed y with t to get parametric: $x= \pm\sqrt{(5)^2-t^2}$. This feels intuitive because this is the equation to get x value. I then do the same with x but it doesn't yield the results I expected. Reference question/context is below. I also attempted to graphed it out to visualize it. (am I keying it out in desmos wrongly..? link: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xs93mhsmfd)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your transformation seems wrong,  $x^2+y^2=25$ implies $x=\sqrt{25-y^2}$ not $x=\sqrt{25+y^2}$.

Comment: Ah nice catch, thank you. I've adjusted it.. But still doesn't seem intuitive why can't i plot parametric (blue color - bottom)
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/cdmtyk5ymw